# Trying to show comments in the timeline from a post

Tags: laravel

I use Models for this.

I have this in the User model:

```
public function timeline()
{
    
    $friends = $this->follows()->pluck('id');
    return Tweet::whereIn('user_id', $friends)
                    ->orWhere('user_id', $this->id)
                    ->withLikes()
                    ->latest()
                    ->paginate(25);
}
```

Now I'm trying to show the comments in the timeline (like Facebook under the tweet)

The tablename is "tweets_comments"
-> id
-> tweet_id
-> user_id
-> comment

When I try it from the controller or model I always get no correct answer and
its always empty.

I hope you all can help me.

I want to show it like this:

Tweet 
-> likes 
-> comments

I hope you understand my problem.

Greetings Vali

Comment: It would be great if you specified more details in which context you run this code. What are "controller" and "model" you are talking about.

Comment: What relationships have you set up for your models?